# List<String> issue

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a problem with my small project.

I'm trying to add multiple subjects for all students, but I have no idea how to use List in my main ArrayList of all students. I have tried to use multiple ArrayList, but the code becomes too complicated.

```
/* Main class: */

class Student {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<String> subjects;
  
  public Student(int id, String name, List<String> subjects) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.subjects = subjects;
  }

  public String name() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
  }

  public List<String> getSubjects() {
    Return subjects;
  }

  Public void addSubject(String subject) {
    Subjects.add(subject);
  }
}
```

Tester class:

```
class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> schoolStudents = new ArrayList(5);

    Student st1 = new Student (1, “John Smith”, “Maths”, “English);
    Student st2 = new Student (2, “Alan Smith”, “Physics”, “English);
    Student st3 = new Student (3, “John Jackson”, “History”, “English);
    Student st4 = new Student (4, “John Saxton”, “Maths”, “Physics);
    Student st5 = new Student (5, “Adam Smith”, “Maths”, “English);
}
```

> Error code for ArrayList:

> `java.lang.string cannot be converted to java.util.list`

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Java varargs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs)

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory. You are passing several Strings instead of a List of Strings

Comment: @Stultuske it's because I don't know how to pass a List of Strings in the main body or use it in the ArrayList. I'm completely new to Java.

Comment: @xtougeattack you pass a List the exact same way as any other type. You create a List and pass that.

Comment: Unrelated: ALWAYS prefer to COPY/PASTE error messages. One can see that you manually wrote down that error message here because you got the casing wrong. In programming, any character matters. So: always always always be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor in your `Student` class defines 3 parameters. ID, Name and a List of Subjects yet you attempt to call the constructor with multiple subjects separated by a comma which is not at all possible. However we can leverage the power of [varargs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs) to achieve your particular use-case.

```
public class Student
{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<String> subjects;

  public Student( int id, String name, String... subjects )
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.subjects = Arrays.asList(subjects);
  }
  // Omitted getters/setters
}
```

In this example the last parameter of the constructor is such a vararg. It allows you to add as many Strings as you like which is then converted to a list.

If changing the signature of the `Student` class is not an option you can achieve a similar behavior by converting the subjects to a list when creating the objects like this:
`Student st1 = new Student (1, "John Smith", Arrays.asList( "Math", "English"));`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Just to confirm, there is no need to use getters/setters with it?

Comment: @xtougeattack Yes there is, you still need getters and setters. I just omitted them in my example so it's a bit more concise.

Comment: Note that Arrays.asList(..) produces a fixed-size array.  The List attached to a Student is probably intended to resize.  You can instead use `Arrays.stream(subjects).collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, your class definition is fine.  I would recommend using `List.of` to supply the list of subjects with a minor change in your constructor with some other things I point out at the end.

- adding lists like this is straight forward.
- and you need to copy the supplied list to an new `ArrayList` anyway to avoid shared objects.

You would call it like this.

```
Student student = new Student(1, "Maria", List.of("English", "Algebra"));
```

Look at the modified constructor in your class to see how the list is copied. The reasons are:

- `List.of` is immutable and you want to be able to add subjects.
- You could also use an existing list of subjects but then if that list is altered, so is your list in the `Student` instance.

```
class Student {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<String> subjects;
  
  public Student(int id, String name, List<String> subjects) {
    this.subjects = new ArrayList<>(subjects);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.subjects = subjects;
  }

  public String name() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
  }

  public List<String> getSubjects() {
    Return subjects;
  }

  Public void addSubject(String subject) {
    Subjects.add(subject);
  }
}
```

A few final observations.

- In your `addSubject` method you need to change `Subjects` to `subjects` to match your field name.
- In your `getSubjects` method, you should use `return` and make a defensive copy when you return the list.

```
    return new ArrayList<>(subjects);
```

This is good technique so that someone can't change the original list in your Student instance.

- Lists grow dynamically. ArrayLists are backed by an array and start out with a default size.  So you don't need to specify your list with a size.  Just do the following and make certain you specify the `<>` since it is a generic class.

```
    List<Student> schoolStudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score -3):

The last parameter of your constructor should be a ArrayList of Strings, which does not seem to be a good choice.
But you are passing a single String in your Tester class, see "English" or "Physics".

Change your `List<String> subjects` to `String subjects`

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem, unless it's ok to just save all subjects as one combined string.